# Is there a Preprocessed Razor Template for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, razor, xamarin

I am going thru this article [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/) which talks about using the Razor template for Xamarin forms. I am however unable to find such a template in Visual Studio. The closest I came to was a nuget package. I don't think I can use that if I am to follow the example in the article above. Has anyone found any such problem before or can this only be done on Xamarin studio?

Why would they not make a provision for Visual Studio as well!

Comment: The razor template is a completely "blank" `.cshtml` file in Xamarin Studio. The key being the `RazorTemplatePreprocessor` build type so the C# file is generated....  In Visual Studio make sure that you have Asp.Net MVC add-in installed... Start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg606533(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Its Visual Studio 2015 so it already has that installed. That article you linked is pretty old. I'm not sure how to use that to generate that template.

Comment: Here is the basis of the Xamarin/MonoDevelop design time Razor custom tool, https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator (Check the VS Extension Gallery)....

Answer (score 5):

Just tried to use a razor template inside a *Xamarin.Forms* PCL and stumbled over the missing template. But then I followed the advice in the comments and it worked without any problems.

1. Add a new class (or whatever you want) to the portable project and name the file `RazorTest.cshtml`.
2. Replace the content of the new file with a skeleton like this:

Adjust the namespace and bind to your own ViewModel:

```
@using RazorTestNamespace.ViewModels
@model RazorTestViewModel
<html>
<body>
  <h1>@Model.Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Go to the class properties, find the `CustomTool` property and type in `RazorTemplatePreprocessor`. Then VisualStudio magically creates the belonging `RazorTest.cs` file with the code-behind.

[image]

4. Build the HTML when needed:

Inside the ViewModel:

```
RazorTest razorTest = new RazorTest { Model = razorTestViewModel };
string html = razorTest.GenerateString();
```

Comment: This looks promising. Will try it out soon. Thanks.

Comment: Not working for me in VS 2017, even the code-behind c# file is also not created

Comment: @JaydeepKarena - What project type do you have? Did you rename the file to *.cshtml before setting the CustomTool to RazorTemplatePreprocessor? I'm working with VS 2017 as well.

Comment: My project type is Mobile Apps ( Xamarin Forms ), trying razor. Done everything you said. Do you have any sample code available, if you can provide

Comment: @JaydeepKarena - For some reason the `.cshtml` cannot be placed inside a shared project (not sure about the PCL), instead one has to add it to the platform specific project(s).

Comment: This works on Visual Studio 2022 - but first when pasting RazorTemplatePreprocessor as the custom tool, an install extension dialog comes up. You need to install the extension before the CS file generation starts working. Thanks @martinstoeckli!

Comment: I'm having trouble now getting this working with a Maui application. I'm wondering if it still works for such a project. Using VS 2022 as before.

Comment: Never tried this in a Maui application, but if you can use Maui, give Blazor hybrid a try. Blazor is built for this and the Html gui plays very well together with the CSharp code.