# How to add Razor file to Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, razor

I'm trying to get Razor working inside my Xamarin project and I can't seem to get Visual Studio 2017 to recognize that the files need to be processed by the Razor preprocessor.

When I go to add a new file, there's no template for `Razor` or `.cshtml`, so I'm just adding a text file and change the extension to `.cshtml`. Then, in the file properties, I'm setting the `Custom Tool` to `RazorTemplatePreprocessor`.

However, despite doing this, Visual Studio does not generate the .cs file that I expect it to.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE AND WORKAROUND**: As a result of helpful conversation with @SushiHangover (see answer and comment chain below), it appears that .NET Standard library projects do not currently allow Razor files to be added through the Add Item wizard, and if you add them manually, they don't compile correctly. this is true as of Visual Studio 15.5.2. I've opened a bug with Microsoft, but in the meantime, I have super clunky workaround, which is as follows.

At the end of the day, Razor files as you might use them in a Xamarin project are only there to generate .cs files, which compile into classes containing a `GenerateString` method, which code can call to generate HTML that can then be fed into a WebView. So, I figured, why not just create a regular .NET Framework library (*not* .NET Standard) and put all my Razor files there. In that project, you can add them normally and they work properly.

But since the rest of my project is .NET Standard and I didn't want to mix and match, I don't actually have any of the other projects reference this library. Instead, I just *include the generated .cs files as links* (click the little arrow next to the Add button and choose Add as Link instead) in my "real" project (the one where I wanted to add them originally). So the library with Razor files has only one purpose, and that is to generate .cs files, period. Those files are actually compiled into a different library.

I hope this helps someone! When Microsoft fixes the bug, I'll update this thread again (and move my Razor files back to where they ought to be).

**EDIT 2**
Microsoft has marked my bug "Under Consideration." If this issue affects you, please upvote it to encourage them to fix it sooner rather than later.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/172997/razor-templates-not-working-for-net-standard-proje.html

Comment: What makes you think Razor files would be used by Xamarin?

Comment: The official Xamarin documentation. (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/) They're a convenient way to dynamically generate HTML that you can then feed into a WebView. I have these working in a different project, but I'm not the one who set it up originally and I can't seem to figure out how he did it.

Answer (score 4):

The Razor file templates are available on Visual Studio for Mac (`VS4M`) under the `"Text Templating"` group, but the recent versions of Visual Studio for Windows (`VS4W`) they have gone missing.

On VS4W, you can just edit the `.csproj` that you are trying to add a Razor file:

1. A `Compile` item for the generated `.cs` file that includes a `DependentUpon` tag for the `.cshtml` file.
2. A `None` item for the `.cshtml` that includes the `Generator` and `LastGenOutput` tags
3. Create those two files (`.cshtml` & `.cs`) (they can be empty to start)

#### Example (Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, & PCL projects)

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="RazorTemplate.cs">
      <DependentUpon>RazorTemplate.cshtml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
 </ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="RazorTemplate.cshtml">
      <Generator>RazorTemplatePreprocessor</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>RazorTemplate.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

#### Example (NetStandard 2.0 project)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Condition=" '$(EnableDefaultCompileItems)' == 'true' " Update="RazorTemplate.cs">
    <DependentUpon>RazorTemplate.cshtml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="RazorTemplate.cshtml">
    <Generator>RazorTemplatePreprocessor</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>RazorTemplate.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there a certain kind of project this needs to be in? I just discovered something interesting. Everything works great when I try to add this to a Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android project. But if I try to add it to the "parent" Xamarin project, it doesn't work. (The two files correctly fold together, but the .cs file is never updated.)

I even tried creating a .cshtml file in the Android project, verifying that it worked, and then dragged it up into the parent project, and I got the same effect. 

Can I sprinkle some magic dust on the project file to make it work?

Comment: @BrianRak What kind of "parent project" is it?

Comment: From the New Project wizard, if you choose Cross-Platform App > you're given the chance to choose Platforms, UI Technology, and Code Sharing Strategy. In my case, if it matters, I choose Android and iOS, Native, and .NET Standard. What is then created for you are three projects, one for each of the native projects, and one that both of the above refer to, for shared code. It's this project that I was calling the "parent." I can now confirm that Razor files are working in the native app projects. But I want to have them live in a single location that can be accessed by both.

Comment: @BrianRak Oh, those are not parent projects, PCL/NetStd projects would be reference projects, the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android application projects would be the "target (parent) projects" The `RazorTemplatePreprocessor` will work in PCL and NetStandard libraries, the format for NetStd is a little different in order for the project items to appear correctly in the solution explorer, see my updated answer.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help! I tried the new format, but it still doesn't quite work. Weirdly, within Solution Explorer, I can see generated methods and properties like I would expect for the .cs file, except they show up as children of the .cshtml file. Since this is probably hard to visualize, here's a screenshot:

https://brakrandomstandard.blob.core.windows.net/ad-hoc/RazorIssuesDotNetStandard.PNG

Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: @BrianRak Not sure I see what the problem with that is...?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. First, what you can't see in the screenshot is that the .cs file is still blank regardless of whether I save the file or compile the project. Also, notice that what appears to be generated class information has a crazy name corresponding to a directory (normally it should just be the name of the file). Again, the actual .cs file is empty. Finally, notice that the generated stuff appears as a child of the .cshtml file (normally it is a child of the .cs file). 

Maybe it's just time for a re-install of VS? Thanks for hanging in here with me.

Comment: @BrianRak Well I just tried it on VS4W 15.6-1.1 and it does not work on NetStd projects, PCL are OK.... VS4M does work.... Report it as a bug in the version that you are using...

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've opened a bug with Visual Studio. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/172997/razor-templates-not-working-for-net-standard-proje.html)

I'm experimenting with workaround steps and will update my question shortly. I'm also upvoting your answer, though I'm not sure if I should mark it as the solution just yet. Thank you again for all your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer as I misunderstood the question so the answer is actually what @SushiHangover put above...

To get the Xamarin Razor pages the project has to be a WebViewApp and then you can add New PreProcessed Razor View to the project.

From the Xamarin Blog on the subject.

> See our Building Hybrid apps with Xamarin documentation to get started building Razor Hybrid applications. Simply use Xamarin Studio to create a new WebView Application for iOS or Android, or add a WebView to any existing iOS or Android layout, and use Add New…Preprocessed Razor Template to incorporate Razor-powered web views into your Xamarin apps. For a slightly more complex sample of a data-driven Razor hybrid app, check out our RazorTodo app.

[The documentation can be found here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/)

[More detail here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/#Using_Razor_Templates_with_Xamarin) as this details how to add the Razor view to each project.

Comment: "Note that you can easily add a .cshtml Razor template to any existing Xamarin project, **it is not necessary to use these solution templates.**" The templates are missing, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2022 I refer you to this answer that worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41116061/812013

When I entered 'RazorTemplatePreprocessor' for the file's custom tool as the answer suggests, I initially didn't notice that Visual Studio opens a dialog asking you to install a ASP .NET extension first. Once I installed this extension, I was then getting a cs file generating from a cshtml file.